# Extract the path from a full file-name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I m new in VBA and below is my code which is not working, can any one of u can help?

```
Dim nPath1() As String
nPath1() = Split(nPath, "\")       

'Declare path as integer
 Dim path As Integer
'Getting array length
 path = UBound(nPath1())
 Dim lastname As String
 'For Loop
 For i = 0 To path-1
     lastname += nPath1(i)+"\"
 Next i
```

The above code is not working; my path string is **Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC\NOC** and what I want is **Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to remove just the last item from your path, you can do it this way:

```
Left(nPath, InStrRev(nPath, "\") - 1)
```

- `InStrRev` finds the position of the last occurrence of `\`
- `Left` truncates the string until that position
- The `-1` is because you want also to remove that last `\`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try:

```
Sub sTest1()
 Dim nPath1 As Variant, st As String
 st = "Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC\NOC"
 nPath1 = Split(st, "\")
 ReDim Preserve nPath1(UBound(nPath1) - 1)
 st = Join(nPath1, "\")
 Debug.Print st
End Sub
```

This is useful if you want to remove more than one item (not just the last one) by changing `1` to 2 or 3 for example:

```
Sub sTest2()
 Dim nPath1 As Variant, st As String, n As Long
 st = "Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC\NOC"

 For n = 1 To 3
    nPath1 = Split(st, "\")
    ReDim Preserve nPath1(UBound(nPath1) - n)
    Debug.Print Join(nPath1, "\")
 Next
```

Results:

```
Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC
Root\zTrash - No longer needed
Root
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are fan of long formulas, this is another option:

```
left(nPath,len(nPath)-len(split(nPath,"\")(ubound(split(nPath,"\")))))
```

- The idea is that you split by `\`
- Then you get the last value in the
  array (with ubound, but you split twice)
- Then you get the difference between it and the whole length
- Then you pass this difference to the left as a parameter

Comment: i like it. But if npath="" , it wil error because split is not friendly to vbnullstring. Wonder if its faster then ASH's solution though.

Comment: Like it, too +:) FYI Posted a late alternative to your post via direct split item removal (i.e. no vbnullstring issue) @Vityata

Answer (score 0):

**Approach using `Filter()` and one `Split()` action**

In addition to @Vityata 's answer I demonstrate an array alternative
accepting also `vbNullString` as `FullPath` argument.

Based on the same idea to make disappear the last split token, this approach doesn't calculate item lengths, but removes the last item directly via `Filter(a, a(Ubound(a)), False)`.

```
Function getPath(FullPath As String, Optional Delim As String = "\") As String
    Dim a: a = Split(FullPath & "$", Delim)
    getPath = Join(Filter(a, a(UBound(a)), False), Delim)
End Function
```

**Side note to `Split()`**

The addition of `& "$"` to FullPath argument is necessary to make the last split item unique,
otherwise it would remove **all** `NOC` tokens, not only the last item. So an Example call like
`Debug.Print getPath("Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC\NOC")` returns the wanted result `Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC`.

If an empty string would be splitted, there won't occur an error as the zero array boundaries (i.e. 1 item) *"join"* to another `vbNullString`.

Answer (score -1):

This

```
For i = 0 To path-1
```

gives you full nPath1 array. If you want to skip last element (and I'm not sure what you exactly want), you should use path-2