# How to remove the last name from a path in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA i'm working on below task

```
nPath = "Root\zTrash - No longer needed\NOC\NOC"
```

I want to remove `\NOC` from `nPath` so that only `Root\zTrash - No longer needed` should be displayed.

I'm using this code:

```
=(Left(nPath, InStrRev(nPath, "\") - 1))
```

But i'm getting only NOC

Comment: By the way, your title is not correct, as it says *"remove the last element from a path"*, and it appears to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462625/how-to-remove-the-last-element-from-a-path-in-vba/42462687#42462687

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of [How to remove the last element from a path in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462625/how-to-remove-the-last-element-from-a-path-in-vba)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Left(nPath, InStr(nPath, "\NOC") - 1)
```

---

You are using `InStrRev` to find the *last* `\` -- that's not what you want. Use `InStr` with `\NOC` to find the *first* instance of `\NOC`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two phases:

```
Dim newString as String
newString = Left(nPath, InStrRev(nPath, "\") - 1)
newString = Left(newString , InStrRev(newString , "\") - 1)
```