# retrieve folder path from file path

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to select the file from filedialog function and storing the file path in string. but I also want the folder name of the selected path. Can you please advise as to how to get the folder path from select file.

File selected is :

```
U:\public\2016\Macro\CD-CW\109 file.xlsx
```

I want to show till :

```
U:\public\2016\Macro\CD-CW\
```

**My Code**

```
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select the file."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2010", "*.xlsx"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    If .Show = True Then
        selfile = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove the last element from a path in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462625/how-to-remove-the-last-element-from-a-path-in-vba)

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42462687/4926357)

Comment: [Use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject/11587/retrieve-only-the-path-from-a-file-path). It's much less error prone than parsing text.

Answer (score 9):

This is very simple:

```
Dim filePath, directoryPath As String
filePath = "U:\public\2016\Macro\CD-CW\109 file.xlsx"
directoryPath = Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
```

Comment: NO, this has not just happened, how can you type that fast :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Left` with `InStrRev` functions to remove the last string after the first `\` found from the right side.

```
Dim FilePath As String

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select the file."
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2010", "*.xlsx"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    If .Show = True Then
        FilePath = Left(.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(1), "\"))
        Debug.Print FilePath 
        selfile = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
    End If
End With
```

Comment: It's not me. I made my remark in the comments section but I'm not into downvoting good answers though :)

Comment: @A.S.H I didn't think so, just curious who, and more to why ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to create a simple function for extracting a folder path from a file that is inside this folder path. My question and proposal is here [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232772/get-folder-path-from-file-inside-this-folder-path-in-excel-vba/58232773#58232773). Function code is below:

```
Function getFolderPathFromFilePath(filePath As String) As String

    Dim lastPathSeparatorPosition As Long

    lastPathSeparatorPosition = InStrRev(filePath, Application.PathSeparator)

    getFolderPathFromFilePath = Left(filePath, lastPathSeparatorPosition - 1)

End Function
```

In some solutions for this purpose, I used FSO, but it takes resources, and I think it isn't worthy to create FSO object if you need it only for this simple function.